# multiple nodes in cts:similar-query

Tags: marklogic

I'm assuming that when I include multiple nodes in the cts:similar-query, the most "relevant" terms will be chosen that would give back new nodes that are "most like" all of the nodes that are passed in - some sort of most distinctive "terms" from all the nodes (i.e., what "terms" are needed to get the nodes to be the top answers).  So, the more nodes you add, the less likely it will be that the results will be "close" to any one of the nodes?

Additionally, I take it that this is different than if I took the nodes and created separate cts:similar-query for each of them and ANDed them together before submitting the search?

And that it is also different that if I OR'd them together before submitting the search?

The ANDing would give fewer, more precise results where only the overlap between the multiple cts:similar-query results while the ORing would possibly boost the intersecting results, which still could be outweighed with a high enough similar-query score?

Answer (score 3):

`cts:similar-query` in effect takes the top N (by default 16) terms and constructs an or-query out of them. It is, as you say, like taking the results from `cts:distinctive-terms`. "Top" is determined by scoring, which by default is logtfidf scoring, so both the frequency within the target nodes and the relative frequency in the database as a whole come into play.

The pool of terms is determined from the input node or nodes. If you have multiple nodes, it could be that a top term is not in one of those nodes. Also, the term frequencies will be different, because it is the sum across all the input nodes, so the scores will be different, and that could affect which terms are selected.

Using a pool of documents in one `cts:similar-query` call means that strong outliers may skew the results away from a prototypical document, but it also means that more of the variance within the pool is captured. I'd avoid using a pool of documents that aren't already similar in the way you care about, but it can be useful if you want to even out minor variations. I suspect it is more useful with smaller documents that provide smaller pools of terms to consider.